# PostgreSQL jsonb - searching string through array elementrs

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Case 1 (works fine) : my db entry is a simple object

```
employee_id | data (jsonb)
4           | {"name":"john"}

SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE data ? 'john';
```

It will correctly find the whole entry

Case 2 : my db entry is an array of elements

```
employee_id | data
4           | [{"name":"john"},{"city":"rio"}]
```

I can't manage to use a jsonb function to find rows that match `'john'` anywhere. At best I can use `WHERE data->0 ? 'john'` but this is not supposed to depend on the index of the array entry

Thx!

Comment: Your "working" example doesn't because `'john'` is not the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jsonb` “contains” operator `@>` like this:

```
... WHERE data @> '[{"name": "john"}]'
```

That will find all rows where `data` has an array on the top level that contains this entry.